# Programmatic Link Scanning

Tags: malware

I'm looking for a programmatic link scanning solution. There are lots of home use software packages that will scan urls on a search results page and verify that those sites don't have malware on them, but I'm looking for a piece of software that you can do this programmatically. I want to be able to feed the code a url, have it do a remote request and scan the web page looking for malware.
Has anyone come across something like that before?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is programming related?  Surely there are enough free download sites and forums to find this information.

Answer (score 5):

[Google safebrowsing](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/)

> " ..is an experimental API that enables client applications to check URLs against Google's constantly updated blacklists of suspected phishing and malware pages. Your client application can use the API to download an encrypted table for local, client-side lookups of URLs that you would like to check."

Comment: I'll make one for you if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Google Search performs this task. Popular browsers also already check suspicious sites against a blacklist. Is there a compelling reason that you think you can do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my site takes user input and then emails our customers with some of that information.  We want to be able to check the links for malware before we forward them on and possibly infect our customers.  I'd honestly prefer to use a pre existing piece of software for this.  I just know that I need to do this in Code and not rely on a standalone piece of software since it needs to be automated.  Ideally, we'd like to check the links when the form is submitted...

Comment: On StackOverflow, comments that aren't answers (like your reply is) should be left as comments to the answer you're replying to (as I am). The answers can get reordered based on votes and it's difficult to tell who's replying to what otherwise

Comment: @Gareth Good tip, but he would need 50 rep to be able to write comments (http://stackoverflow.com/faq). He has only 31 rep at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of relevant resources: http://www.malwarehelp.org/freeware-open-source-commercial-website-security-tools-services-downloads.html