# Url filtering

Tags: security, url, malware, malware-detection

I'm looking for way to verify whether a site is categorized in any url filtering databases.
Does somebody know such database with free API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic Link Scanning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381747/programmatic-link-scanning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Google Safe Browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/). It allows you to check URLs against Google's blacklists of suspected phishing and malware pages. Here is [the developer guide](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide.html).

Answer (score 2):

BrightCloud just released an [API for URL classification](http://bcws.brightcloud.com) that is more comprehensive than the Google Safe Browsing API - it does cost money but it's cheap.  In addition to categories like "Adult" and "Gambling" it also has security oriented categories like phishing, malware, and spam.

The full list of categories is here: http://brightcloud.com/masterdburllist.asp

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the SimilarWeb API. The API will perform domain level classification and is based on SimilarSite’s content analysis and machine learning.

Link to the API: https://developer.similarweb.com/

Disclosure, I’m affiliated with SimilarGroup, the creator of SimilarWeb.