# Service to check a URL for malware or phishing?

Tags: php, web-services, security, phishing

Is there a service that lets me check a URL to see if it may possibly be a dangerous site?

When a user exits our application by clicking on an untrusted link, we sent them through a "are you sure you want to leave" redirection screen. It'd be a nice touch to do a quick check to see if we should warn the user as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic Link Scanning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381747/programmatic-link-scanning)

Answer (score 10):

Try with [Google Safe Browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/lookup_guide.html).

> The Google Safe Browsing Lookup API is an experimental API that allows applications to check URLs against Google's constantly-updated lists of suspected phishing and malware pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Safe Browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/) to check if a URL is safe according to what they know about it. ([API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/lookup_guide.html))

Answer (score -1):

How about z-protect.com?

Example report: http://www.z-protect.com/report/stackoverflow.com/
this system is using a dns server to block the pages ... maybe interessting?

An this service has a api! but with a limit of 10000 requests per day:
http://www.z-protect.com/api

Comment: z-protect.com is out of service